# Contents of UIViewController not adapting to iPhone 4s layout

Tags: iphone, xcode, autolayout, uistoryboard, label

I have a view controller with some fixed labels, steppers etc. The layout looks fine in iPhone5, 6/6 plus, but when i try in iPhone4s the view just doesnt scroll down to show other content.

Should the scrollbar not appear automatically when the content does not fit in screen size?

Here is how the layout in iPhone 4s looks along with how it should actually look

[image]

It would be great if someone can help me identify why is the content not scrolling for iPhone4s

Thanks in advance

Comment: you need to use scrollview and make sure that constraints work with your objects

Answer (score 0):

No, it should not scroll automatically. You need to embed your view into a scroll view or (better) use table view.

Comment: so does it mean that i will have to rearrange everything with respect to scrollview again?

Comment: Right now I have fixed all the elements with respect to view controller? is there some way so that i dont require to change all the margins and constraints? plss help

Comment: Place your entire view into an UIScrollView.

Comment: now the hierarchy has chaged to View>Scrollview>View and then the elements. bt still nothing works.. the scrollview also doesnt adjust itself